# Restrict Azure web app access to Security Group/Distribution group

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app that I am hosting on Azure and would like to know how I can make that site accessable by only a security group/distribution list within Azure.

Now, the url is accessable by anyone even outside of my tenant which I am trying to avoid - What route would I go down to restrict it down to groups? I can't do it by users because there are 1,000+ users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like you can only restrict an Azure Web App access via IP addresses or virtual networks. Below is a quick summary. However, I have attached a link to the [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions#adding-and-editing-access-restriction-rules-in-the-portal) that explains in more detail how to implement adding these restrictions.

- Go to your service in the Azure Portal > Networking > IP Restrictions
- Add Rule
- Input IP/subnet mask
- Note: After you add a rule, it will create an implicit deny by default for anything requests not matching the rules.

[This link](https://cmatskas.com/restrict-public-access-to-your-azure-web-apps-with-the-ipsecurityrestrictions-object/) also may be helpful if you want to edit the `web.config` instead of using the Azure Portal.